# get collection of child nodes in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to find out how to collect *just* the `li` child nodes inside a `ul` element. I can't seem to figure out how to limit `watir` to just the direct `li` child nodes, and not the ones further down in the document.

```
b = Watir::Browser.start "http://example.com"
section_list = b.ul(:id => 'section_list')
section_list.lis #=> this returns *all* the li elements until section_list
```

Is there an option to watir that says only do the first level?

Comment: Depending on the page's html, you could be more specific about what lis the collection returns.

Comment: Could you expand on that?

Comment: Just like getting an element, you can get an element collection based on each element's properties. For example, perhaps the first level li's are the only ones with a specific class, then you could do `section_list.lis(:class=>'firstlevel')`. If you share the html of your page, I could give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Oh, sure, I see what you mean. That, sadly, is not the case (shakes fist at devs!!), which is why I'm resorting to the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
Then(/^the element with id of "(.*?)" should have (\d+) children$/) do |id, n|
  el = @browser.element(:id => id)
  el.elements(:xpath, "./*").count.should eql(n.to_i)
end
```

Comment: You can use just `"*"` instead of `"./*"`.